# a bug in my Palindrome code . My function runs fine except when i call ('abba') returns false instead of True . Why

Tags: python, string

A palindrome is a word, phrase, number or other sequence of units that can be read the same way in either direction. Write a function that determines whether the given word or number is a palindrome.

```
def isPalindrome(word1):
 c=''   
 for l in reversed(str(word1)):
  c+=l  #reversed word
 if (str(c).lower()==str(word1).lower())&len(str(word1))<>0:
  return True 
 else :
  return False
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def isPalindrome(word1):
 c=''   
 for l in reversed(str(word1)):
  c+=l  #reversed word
 if (str(c).lower()==str(word1).lower()) and len(str(word1))!=0:
  return True 
 else :
  return False
```

**Just some syntax errors:**

- In Python, the syntax for "and" is simply `and`, not `&`.
- In Python 3, the syntax for "not equal" is `!=`, not `<>`. However, in Python 2, this is valid syntax. It is still better to use `!=` to maintain compatibility across versions.

Comment: no it's definitely not this try it yourself with !=0 it does not work for ('abba') it returns false

Comment: The main issue is the use of the `&` instead of `and`. The `!=0` works for Python 2, but not Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is cheating a little, but why do you not use something like:

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    if word.lower() == word[::-1].lower():
        return True
    return False
```

where `word[::-1]` is simply your input reversed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPalindrom(word):
    for (c1,c2) in zip(word,reversed(word)):
        if c1.lower()!=c2.lower():
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the following logic

```
def isPalindrome(word1):
    c=0   
    for l in reversed(str(word1)):   
        if (str(word1[c]).lower()==l.lower()):
            c+=1  
            continue
        else :
            return False 
    return True

print(isPalindrome('12311'))
```